# Modifying parsed Atom feed in Ruby

Tags: ruby, rss, atom-feed

I need to modify the contents of an Atom feed parsed using the standard RSS library. I've found documentation for parsing and generating feeds, but nothing about the correct way to modify existing structure (maybe it's deemed obvious?).

Specifically, I'm trying to add a `content` element to each `entry`, with a type of 'html' and wrapped in a CDATA section.

This is what I have so far:

```rb
feed = RSS::Parser.parse open(some_uri), true
feed.items.each do |item|
  item.content = RSS::Atom::Feed::Entry::Content.new
  item.content.type = 'html'
  item.content.content = '<html>my content that i have</html>'
end
```

Is that the preferred way, and if so, how do I add the CDATA tag?

Comment: I'd recommend using [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org) to modify it. I've found that RSS/Atom and other "similar" feed types, are different enough that the RSS library breaks down when you try to get fancy. Nokogiri doesn't care, it just parses XML, and will let you modify it to your heart's content.

Comment: That's actually the main reason I'm using the RSS library - I want to normalize to Atom from various versions of RSS, and assumed it would be better at that than something hand-rolled. Seems to be working well enough so far.

Comment: It might work well for you. I was processing several thousand feeds and the "variety" of different formats, because the specs have been so badly abused, made that code misbehave. I eventually wrote my own to handle everything I was seeing.